# Problema con celdas en libre office Version: 7.6.5.2 (X86_64) / LibreOffice Community

Tags: libreoffice-calc

acabo de abrir mi libre office y se muestra de la siguiente manera:

[image: problema con office calc]

Porque ya no puede visualizar las celdas vacias? Hay forma de configurarlo de nuevo para que este como antes?

Comment: Puedes seguir los pasos que indica este post: https://www.trishtech.com/2020/08/how-to-reset-libreoffice-to-factory-settings/

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.